# Confidence interval for graph

Tags: r, group-by, confidence-interval

I am trying to plot a graph using a code that I had previously written and used but now is giving me headaches. I think it may be because of the interaction between the packages Rmisc and dplyr, at least I get a notice if I call the package Rmisc after dplyr. Is there a way around it?

```
  library(Rmisc)
  library(dplyr)
  Desc <- Acc %>%
  group_by(Epoch, Probability, Session) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(Acc), CI = CI(Acc, ci=0.95)[1]- CI(Acc, ci=0.95)[2])
```

Expected:

```
Epoch Probability Session mean    CI 
 1         1          1     0.89    0.002
 2         1          2     0.87    0.001
```

...

instead I get this:

```
 mean    CI
 0.96     0.002
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this issue with Rmisc is because the installation of dplyr or Rmisc is broken is difficult to tell without your 'sessionInfo()', but the following trick should work for you. Note that the function CI is eactly the same as in Rmisc. Just do Rmisc::CI in console to see by yourself. Up vote if you find this helpful.

```
library(dplyr)
same_CI <- function (x, ci = 0.95) 
{
  a <- mean(x)
  s <- sd(x)
  n <- length(x)
  error <- qt(ci + (1 - ci)/2, df = n - 1) * s/sqrt(n)
  return(c(upper = a + error, mean = a, lower = a - error))
}
Desc <- Acc %>%
      group_by(Epoch, Probability, Session) %>%
      summarise(mean = mean(Acc), 
                up = same_CI(Acc)[1],
                low = same_CI(Acc)[3],
                CI = up - low)
```

Update

Just notice that you were substracting the mean from the upper confidence interval, maybe that was the error. And one more thing make sure you have got the correct levels in your Acc dataset.